# anaconda not installing numba 0.43

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, numba

From the numba website I see that the latest version is 0.43 and my current version is 0.42, but when I do

> conda update numba

nothing happens. The same with pip.
Do I simply need to wait some time until it becomes available?

Comment: Afaik it has not yet been released, since the RC is still waiting for the checks of numpy 1.16 support to complete. I the change has alread been posted on the website, while it is not yet on the release channel. Furthermore if you want to update numba with conda, you should better try `conda update numba -c numba` to be on the numba release channel.

Comment: Indeed using  ```conda update numba -c numba``` I get the 0.43 version

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, the official anaconda website provides the actual commands to install the python packages with conda. For instance for Numba, you can visit: https://anaconda.org/numba/numba which gives the answer the OP was looking for.